# Simple Application of Prime Number Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was wondering if someone could possibly help
me verify the following:

For sufficiently large $n$ there is always a prime between
$n- \sqrt{n}$ and $n$.

I am not sure if this is true or not. If it is true could you 
possibly explain me how the Prime number theorem is
applied to get the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think you will have an easy time proving this result. There are a number of reasons for this. First, the [Legendre conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) states that there is at least one prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$, an interval of length that is order of $n$. As far as I know this is still unsolved. If we rescale your problem, we get that you want to show there are primes between $n^2-n$ and $n^2$ for $n$ large enough. Notice that $(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1<n^2-n$. So if you could show your statement to be true, then you will have proven the Legendre conjecture for large enough $n$, and if you could produce a good lower bound on $n$ then a computer search will likely prove the Legendre conjecture.

The prime number theorem says $\pi(n)=O(n/\log(n))$. In fact the limit of the ratio is 1. So for all $0<C<1$, there exists a $N_c$, such that for all $n\geq N_c$,

$$c\leq \frac{\pi(n)}{n/\log(n)}$$

The interval you have is of length $\sqrt{n}$. In fact, the interval $[1,n]$ can be broken into $[1,n-\sqrt{n}]$ and $[n-\sqrt{n},n]$. In other words, you could try showing that there are at least $n-\sqrt{n}$ primes. No matter what $c$ you chose in the above, you will not attain a density this high for all large $n$.

You also might be interested in the [Oppermann Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture) which is a somewhat stronger version of your problem.

Comment: Now reread the question title: "Simple application ..." :)

Comment: You could try looking for asymptotic results of Legendre's conjecture. I'm not an expert but I don't think much is known.

Comment: Ooopps. I guess it's not simple after all. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is the lower part of Oppermann's conjecture that I think to have proved in a publication available at:
http://www.scienpress.com/journal_focus.asp?main_id=60&Sub_id=IV&Issue=1263 
and for which I still wait some commentaries.
The title of this article is 'From Sierpinski's conjecture to Legendre'. It has been published in the journal Theoretical Mathematics & Applications, vol.4, no.2, 2014, 65-77, ISSN: 1792-9687 (print), 1792-9709 (online) Scienpress Ltd, 2014. In this article, I show that Sierpinski's, Oppermann's and Legendre's conjectures (see Wikipedia for definitions), all dealing with N², can be integrated into a new global D conjecture which possesses a property of recurrence.This property is used to prove these three linked conjectures respecting the order: Oppermann's first and conditional to D, Sierpinski's second and conditional to D, D third and unconditional, Oppermann's and Sierpinski's fourth and unconditional, and finally Legendre's.
Regards.

Comment: Can you give at least a short description? Even if the main point in an answer is a link, the answer should be able to be meaningful alone. Also, if you provide the name and other details of the publication, your answer remains useful even if the link dies.